# Will a Airport Utility archive action delete files on the target disk?

Tags: time-machine, airport, archive

Will an Airport Utility archive action delete files on the target disk?

I have an older Apple Time Capsule 2TB and I have a Laccie 6TB USB3.0 drive connected to it in "safe 3TB" configuration. In my Airport Utility app, it shows both disks.

The Laccie disk is already half full of stuff I put on it. I want to move 400MB of files from the Time Machine disk over to the Laccie disk but it says it will take over 24 hours.

So, I was thinking about using the Airport Utility "Archive" function to backup all the files on my Time Capsule over to the Laccie but I am afraid it might overwrite existing files already on that target disk.

Should I worry about when the "archive" function occurs, does it create a time-stamped folder?  I could find no information on exactly what happens when the "archive" function does its work.

### EDIT:

I found a [partial answer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1281) to my question:

Answer (score 1):

When the "archive" backs up files from the source disk, it puts the files into a sub-directory called "Time Capsule Backup" on the destination disk.  There is no timestamp on the destination folder name.  The files are not zipped up in an archive either.   Now I understand how the backup is able to generate a backup without deleting any files on the destination disk.