# If I archive the "DATA" on my AirPort Time Capsule to an external drive will it affect that drive's data?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I'm new to using the AirPort Utility. I just want to backup the data on an old AirPort Time Capsule of a freind's to their external LaCie drive:

[image]

I click on "Archive Disk", and I'm prompted with this:

[image]

The data that are currently on LaCie need to be kept. Will the process of clicking "Archive Disk" and then "Archive" on the destination drive "LaCie" affect the files currently on "LaCie"? I want both what is currently on "LaCie" and the "Data" that is on the AirPort Time Capsule.

---

Update: Actually, the "related" post I linked to below links to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1281) page, which states the following:

[image]

---

Note: The file system types might be different. I believe the LaCie drive was made APFS.

Comment: I guess not? Click [here](https://www.macobserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/You-Sure.jpg). [Source](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/macos-archiving-time-capsule/).

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186410/will-a-airport-utility-archive-action-delete-files-on-the-target-disk

Comment: What about just creating a disk image?

Comment: I already backed it up. It took 18+ hours to backup a little less than 1TB... Kinda strange... Now I have a file called "AirPort Time Capsule Archive_temp" and in it is a .sparsebundle file titled "[name]'s MacBook Pro (499)", where "[name]" is the name of my friend. I suppose this is a 1TB file containing the data for the backups on the old MacBook Pro. Not sure what the 499 is.